# Can’t figure out why web font isn’t working

Tags: css, font-face

[This page](http://www.timeandoak.com/pages/cocktails) isn’t loading fonts properly and I can’t figure out why.

Here is the current implementation

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'DINPro-Medium';
  src: url('http://timeandoak-shopify.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/assets/fonts/din-medium/DINPro-Medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  url('http://timeandoak-shopify.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/assets/fonts/din-medium/DINPro-Medium.woff') format('woff'), url('http://timeandoak-shopify.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/assets/fonts/din-medium/DINPro-Medium.ttf')  format('truetype'), url('http://timeandoak-shopify.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/assets/fonts/din-medium/DINPro-Medium.svg#DINPro-Medium') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'UnitedSansSemiCond-Medium';
  src: url('http://timeandoak-shopify.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/assets/fonts/united-semi-cond/UnitedSansSemiCond-Medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  url('http://timeandoak-shopify.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/assets/fonts/united-semi-cond/UnitedSansSemiCond-Medium.otf')  format('opentype'),
       url('http://timeandoak-shopify.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/assets/fonts/united-semi-cond/UnitedSansSemiCond-Medium.woff') format('woff'), url('http://timeandoak-shopify.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/assets/fonts/united-semi-cond/UnitedSansSemiCond-Medium.ttf')  format('truetype'), url('http://timeandoak-shopify.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/assets/fonts/united-semi-cond/UnitedSansSemiCond-Medium.svg#UnitedSansSemiCond-Medium') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into the browser console?

> Font from origin 'http://timeandoak-shopify.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.timeandoak.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Good call! Had no idea a font would require CORS config +1

Comment: @KirkStrobeck The ways of the CORS are full of mysteries.